# Integral of the Vandermonde determinant.

Tags: fourier-transform, symmetric-polynomials, random-matrices

For which values of $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_d$ the following integral of the Vandermonde determinant:
$$\mathcal{F}[V](\omega_1,\dots,\omega_d)=\int_\Lambda e^{-i\sum_j \theta_j \omega_j}V(e^{i\theta_1},\ldots,e^{i\theta_d})d{\theta_1}\dots d\theta_d,$$
with $V(e^{i\theta_1},\ldots,e^{i\theta_d})=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq d}(e^{i\theta_j}-e^{i\theta_i})$ and $\Lambda=[0,2\pi]^d$, is non-negative? notice that $\mathcal{F}[V]$ is an integer function (a signed sum of Kronecker deltas).

Comment: You don't say what you have attempted. Have you tried to work cases $d=1,2,3$ ?

Comment: Yes: nothing precisely enlightening on those cases. Applying directly the Leibniz determinant formula leads to a sum of Kronecker deltas indexed by the permutation group on $d$ elements with the sign of each permutation as prefactor, however finding when the number of even nonzero contributions are bigger than the nonzero odd contributions is difficult. Maybe there is connection with the gamma function or beta due to the possible application of a Selberg integral.

Comment: An idea: your integral is the sum of $n!$ integrals obtained by expanding the Vandermonde determinant:

$$(-1)^s\int_\Lambda e^{-i\sum_j \theta_j \omega_j}e^{ i(k_1\theta_1+\cdots + k_d\theta_d)}d{\theta_1}\dots d\theta_d$$
where $s$ is the signature of the permutation, which is easily computed.

Comment: That's precisely my point: determining whether the number of positive signature contributions are bigger than the odd ones is truly hard.

Comment: Sorry, I hadnt read your first comment...

Comment: A very vague idea: could this result have a connection with Bôchner's theorem : "A function is the Fourier transform of a positive measure if and only if it is continuous and positive definite" ?